# Are there diagrams, animations, or even actual photographs of the very first "underground cable" on Mars?

Tags: lander, insight, spaceflight-firsts, seismology, noise

In order to hear earthquakes and other seismic signals better:

> [...(the Insight) mission team has begun trying to partially insulate the (seismometer's) cable from the weather. They've started by using the scoop on the end of InSight's robotic arm to drop soil on top of the domed Wind and Thermal Shield, allowing it to trickle down onto the cable. That allows the soil to get as close to the shield as possible without interfering with the shield's seal with the ground. Burying the seismic tether is in fact one of the goals of the next phase of the mission, which NASA recently extended by two years, to December 2022.](https://phys.org/news/2021-04-nasa-insight-sizable-quakes-mars.html)

**Question:** I'm having trouble imagining what this burial process is like. Are there diagrams, animations, or even actual photographs of this very first instance of [undergrounding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undergrounding) or [direct buried cable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct-buried_cable) on Mars?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The scoop on the end of the robotic arm dug a scoopfull of soil.  It then moved the scoop over the top of the dome, and tipped the scoop to release the soil, which trickled down the dome to the base of the seismometer.  Repeat 4 or 5 times.  This buried several inches of cable, nearest the seismometer, to a depth of just a few millimeters.

Source: Examining the [InSight raw images](https://mars.nasa.gov/insight/multimedia/raw-images/)

[image: buried cable]

Comment: less glamorous than I'd thought; it seems that the [last mile problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Last_mile) hasn't yet been solved on Mars

Comment: It makes one wonder whether the effort to consider the issue, design a solution, manufacture a means of achievement, send it to Mars & then to undertake the endeavor was worth it. Just to put a *few millimeters* of soil on a cable as weather protection.